# Se puede poner código javascrip dentro de un div?

Tags: javascript, html5

Quisiera saber si se puede poner código Javascript dentro de un `div`

Tengo un ejemplo que se puede poner un `style` dentro de un `td`

```
<td valign="top" 
   style='width: 67.0pt; border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: solid #92989D 1.0pt; border-right: solid #92989D 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 15.0pt'>
   <p align=right style='margin-top: 3.0pt; margin-right: 3.5pt; margin-bottom: 0cm; margin-left: 0cm; margin-bottom: .0001pt; text-align: right'>
     <span style='font-size: 7.0pt; font-family: "Arial"'></span>
   </p>
</td>
```

¿Quisiera poner `javascript` dentro de un `div` no se si eso sea posible?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-barcode.min.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/JsBarcode.code39.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- <div id="barcode"></div> -->
    <table border="0" width="220">
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
                <div id="barcode"

                  height="15"
                  width="220"
                />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" width="220">
                <b>@claveAcceso</b>
              </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="barcode">

        </div>

    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#barcode").barcode(
                "2001201901070202304500110011000000000161234567819",
                "code11"
            );
        });

        function textToBase64Barcode(text){
          var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
          JsBarcode(canvas, text, {format: "CODE39"});
          return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Intento hacer un javascript inline

Comment: La unica forma es poniendolo dentro de un evento como `onclick`

Comment: @alanfcm una cosa que no había comentado el html nunca se ejecuta porque es una plantilla que uso para crear pdf desde Windows Forms solo la leo como un string

Comment: html  css y javascript son instrucciones para que un motor de render muestre las cosas, el motor de render puede ser un navegador, una librería que interprete las instrucciones y devuelva un png o una estructura de datos que refleje el DOM. Si el generador de pdf es sólo un parser y no un render el javascript lo mas seguro es que lo ignore. fijate si la librería que usas para generar barcodes incluye la opción de devolver un string bas64 para data url así el html que generas incluye un img con el src adecuado (el barcode ya está renderizado)

Comment: @aloMalbarez la librería que estoy utilizando es: `js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js`, `js/jquery-barcode.min.js`

Comment: @aloMalbarez Seria probar con JsBarcode veo que si se puede devolver un string base64 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35637298/generate-barcode-from-text-and-convert-it-to-base64

Comment: @aloMalbarez actualice el hilo poniendo el código que ocupo

Comment: con qué estás generando el html?  `<b>@claveAcceso</b>` es un placeholder para luego armar el pdf? o se reemplaza por algo antes de que llegue al generador de pdf?

Comment: @aloMalbarez claro estoy usando Razor Engine para ese fin `@Model.ClaveAcceso` cuando recupero el html en un string con razor le paso los datos.respondiendo a tu pregunta el html es uno simple en el cual creo la plantilla esa plantilla solo lo uso para crear el pdf no se renderiza con nada estoy trabajando en Windows Forms

Comment: tendrías que ver de generar el barcode también de esa manera y en el html te quedaría algo así: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,@barcodeEnBase64" alt="@barcodeEnNumeros" />` así te aseguras de que no haga falta un motor de javascript que rellene la plantilla para el generador de pdf ( salvo que el generador de pdfs tenga esa capacidad )

Comment: @aloMalbarez podrías poner tu respuesta implementando el còdigo que compartí

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es totalmente posible poner javascript dentro de un div:

hay ciertas cosas a considerar

- Si estás usando una librería como jQuery, esta debe cargarse antes para estar disponible
- Lo mismo sucede con plugins para jQuery, deben cargarse antes de llamarlos
- Si hacés referencia a un elemento html, éste debe existir antes del javascript
- Si el javascript reemplaza el contenido del div que lo contiene, no vas a ver el código en el inspector pero por lo general podes seguir llamando a las funciones definidas en el script (ejemplo con botones).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsbarcode/3.11.0/barcodes/JsBarcode.code39.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Based-Barcode-Generator-Barcode/jquery-barcode.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="0" width="220">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <div id="barcode" height="15" width="220"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function() {
            $("#barcode").barcode(
              "2001201901070202304500110011000000000161234567819",
              "code11"
            );
          });
        </script>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" width="220">
        <b>@claveAcceso</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div id=otrobarcode>
    <img id=elbarcode src="" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function textToBase64Barcode(text) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        JsBarcode(canvas, text, {
          format: "CODE39"
        });
        return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      }
      elbarcode.src = textToBase64Barcode("2001201901070202304500110011000000000161234567819");
    </script>
  </div>

  <div id=scriptpisador>
    <script>
      function pisadordescripts(texto) {
        scriptpisador.innerHTML = texto;
      }

      function otropisadordescripts(texto) {
        scriptpisador.innerHTML = "otro " + texto;
      }

      pisadordescripts("cambio uno");
    </script>
  </div>

  <script>
    pisadordescripts("cambio dos");
  </script>

  <button onClick="pisadordescripts('cambio boton '+Math.ceil(Math.random()*10));">cambio</button>
  <button onClick="otropisadordescripts('cambio boton '+Math.ceil(Math.random()*10));">cambio2</button>


</body>



</html>
```

Esto es debido a que HTML, CSS y Javascript son instrucciones para que un motor de renderizado dibuje la página y le dé interactividad, el estandar dicta que va de arriba hacia abajo, cargando scripts, cargando css, creando elementos html y ejecutando scripts.
Salvo que las cargas de scripts sean asíncronas, el navegador espera para seguir cargando, creando y ejecutando.

---

En tu caso particular al no tener un motor de render pues el html es una plantilla que luego se convierte a pdf ( por lo general los html2pdf son parsers y no incluyen un motor/vm de javascript ). Lo aconsejable sería hacer lo mismo que estás haciendo con el elemento `<b>@claveAcceso</b>` incrustando una imagen del barcode ya renderizado esto quedaría mas o menos asi:

```
  <table border="0" width="220">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <img id="barcode"
          height="15" width="220"
          src="data:image/png;base64,@barcodeEnBase64" alt="@barcodeEnNumeros" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" width="220">
        <b>@claveAcceso</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Aquí desde el win form deberías buscar un generador de barcodes para rellenar los placeholders `@barcodeEnBase64` y `@barcodeEnNumeros`, de tal manera que el html resultante al pasarlo al generador de pdf ya esté bastante cocinado y no necesite de un motor/intérprete de javascript.

Tal vez debas omitir la parte de `data:image/png;base64,` si el generador de barcode en imagen base64 ya lo incluye (es cuestión de inspeccionar el html generado a ver si se repite esa parte).

Comment: Es así como lo estoy haciendo me refiero a que en el Windows Forms creo con C# una imagen png que es mi código de barra generando ingresandole los números de la clave de acceso.

Comment: Me imaginé, en mi caso lo viví con php y por cuestiones de como entrega el base64 necesitaba el `data:image/png;base64,` que no es muy estandar para pdf ( las imagenes son bitmaps o jpeg ) pero la mayoría de los readers lo toma sin protestar.

Comment: Voy a actualizar la plantilla que no e mi código si la puedes ver para que me sugieras los cambios esta plantilla usa tablas anidadas y si lo remplazo con div creo pudo manejar mejor los style https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/238314/actualizar-plantilla-a-html-5

Answer (score 2):

Que yo recuerde ¡no!, recordá que para hacer uso de javascript debes colocarlo entre las etiquetas `script> /script`

Recordá que al final la idea es que podás realizar tu código lo más limpio y entendible y si querés meter todo en cada elemento no tendría mucho sentido.
De igual manera funciona con CSS, imaginate tener lleno tus elementos html de css, típico caso es donde muchos colocan etiquetas php en el archivo de vista y crean queries en ese archivo, que aunque se puede realizar no es recomendable.

Podriás hacer al como esto, pero colocarlo como un atributo lo dudo, y si se pudiera, que se pueda realizar no significa que sea correcto.

```
<div id="barcode" height="15" width="220">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#barcode").barcode(
                    "2001201901070202304500110011000000000161234567819",
                    "code11"
                );
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: El tema de tenerlo ahí es porque es una plantilla para hacer pdf desde windows form en el cual la plantilla html la seo como un string

Answer (score 2):

Puedes ponerlo y se ejecutará, pero te puede dar problemas debido al tiempo que tarde en cargarse la página, pues puede que algún elemento al que hagas referencia aún no se haya cargado en el [DOM](https://www.w3.org/2005/03/DOM3Core-es/introduccion.html), así como las librerías que, según tu ejemplo, piensas usar.

Sí tomas la precaución de esperar a la carga completa, no deberías tener problemas:

```
<html>
    <div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
             // aquí pones tu código javascript

            });
        </script>
    </div>
</html>
```

De todas formas, el ejemplo del `style` dentro del `td` no es en nada parecido a esto, pues el javascript está **dentro** del `div`, no como uno de sus atributos. El javascript funcionaría igual si lo sacas del `div` y no tendrá ninguna relación respecto al `div` por encontrarse dentro de él.

> Tendrás que prestar especial atención si alguno de estos elementos 
>   con javascript incrustado, lo cargas por ajax, pues podrías tener algún
>   problema adicional. Seguramente tendrás que quitar lo de esperar la
>   carga del DOM, pues el evento `$(document).ready` ya se pasó y tu código no se ejecutará.
>   Aunque esto podría variar según la versión de jquery.

Comment: Ojo: nunca ejecutare el html porque lo uso como plantilla para crear pdf desde windows forms

Comment: @PedroÁvila, si no se ejecuta el HTML ¿que necesitas o esperas que ocurra con el javascript incrustado?

Answer (score 2):

Lo mas parecido a un JavaScript inline es, como ya han comentado por arriba, crear un elemento onload="tufuncion()". Todo lo demás será JavaScript pero no inline. En cualquier caso, según lo que veo en tu código te puede valer si haces esto:

```
<div id="barcode" onload="mifuncion()">

<script type="text/javascript">
function mifuncion(){
    $("#barcode").barcode(
        "2001201901070202304500110011000000000161234567819",
        "code11"
    );


    function textToBase64Barcode(text){
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        JsBarcode(canvas, text, {format: "CODE39"});
        return canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    }
}
</script>
```

Esto no quiere decir que esta sea la forma adecuada de hacerlo, pero tu pregunta es si se puede poner JavaScript inline no si es correcto :D

Comment: Exactamente por que es un caso especial, no estoy implementado en web

Comment: Claro. Con esto según solicites la página HTML te va a cargar el js y pintará en el documento el elemento canvas y lo que haga el barcode.

Answer (score 1):

Mira te dire la forma mas facil.  Es que tienes mucho enredo en el codigo y despues al leerlo te enredaras.

primero. en tu head agrega tus estilos CSS. crea un estilo, ya sea una clase o un id.  A esta clase o ID agregale las propiedades.

segundo. crea tu div y le pones un estilo. por ejemplo.

tercero. creas tu script y le asignas en que atributo lo vas a colocar. Lo puedes hacer de dos maneras. Con js o con jquery. la mas sencilla seria con jquery

$(".ejemplo").show(.barcode(
        "2001201901070202304500110011000000000161234567819",
        "code11"
      );

si lo haces así, tendrás todo organizado. Tus estilos por un lado, tu html por otra, y tu js por otro.
Ten en cuenta que para usar el jquery tienes que importar la libreria de jquery

en tu head agrega