# Actualizar plantilla a HTML 5

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Tengo una plantilla en html que uso para generar un PDF, el tema es que estoy trabajando en Windows Forms, C#, Visual Studio 2015, actualmente si me funciona generar el pdf por medio del html. Pero esta plantilla es una plantilla absoleta ya que usa tablas anidadas cuando se puede usar un div eso es lo que me recomendaron.

Muestro el código del HTML

[Plantilla HTML](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArSzlnjk6KJwh6BO5vif0SEOVYZDQA)

Como puedo usar `div` en vez de `tr` lo he intentado pero no se si se puede hacer eso dentro de un `tbody`?

Me gustaría hacer una plantilla nueva con HTML 5 y usar buenas practicas, lo que espero es que me indiquen que hacer.

NOTA: No renderizo el html nunca lo ejecuto solo lo leo como un string para poder convertirlo a pdf con la librería ITextSharp

Comment: pero las tablas no son obsoletas, pues con ayuda de ellas agrupas información por columnas y filas, el propósito de los `div` no es sustituir a las tablas

Comment: @element ¿pero se puede mejorar el código html?

Comment: no veo como usar `div` mejoraría el código, para empezar si tienes que mostrar información estructurada considero que las tablas son la mejor opción

Comment: si tablas funcionan no hay por qué reemplazarlas, salvo que busques una cuestión semantica con buscadores, en ese caso si los datos tabulados no son "tablas" hay que reemplazar todo:  el table, thead, tbody los th, tr, td etc...

Comment: Esta bien entonces queda como esta, muchas gracias por sus recomendaciones. Lo que me hizo pensar en eso es que no pude ser capaz de poner el border a algunas tablas no sale en el pdf pero cuando uso un navegado si, como por ejemplo: `<table border="1" style="border: solid 5px #D6EAF8; border-radius: 5%">` no me toma el border en pdf me refiero al color no sale nada

Comment: El tema pasa si se puede lucir un poco mas el pdf valiendome de css siempre y cuando sea posible ya que esta llimitado a que no renderizo.

Comment: @PedroÁvila ¿Es obligatorio utilizar iTextSharp? La librería te va a poner en más de un apuro porque el motor de iTextSharp es más bien malo y un código HTML5 válido siguiendo las buenas prácticas tiene muchas papeletas para no ser generado correctamente (ya me he enfrentado antes a este problema cuando tuve que generar pdf de facturas electrónicas). ¿Qué versión de .Net Framework estás utilizando? ¿De cuánto tiempo dispones? Por supuesto, solo digo esto si sigues interesado en usar HTML5 y buenas prácticas

Comment: @RobertoPintosLópez Estoy usando .Net Framework 4.6.1 , puede ser cualquier librería que me permita embellecer el pdf tengo dos días suficiente para modificar la plantilla.

Comment: En ese caso tienes dos opciones. La mejor de todas, sin lugar a dudas, es utilizar puppeteer-sharp, un wrapper de puppeteer (una librería de Google que, entre otras cosas, permite generar PDF) https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp. No te costará nada probar a integrarla. Si es compatible con tu configuración solo tienes que construir el HTML con el CSS y utilizar el ejemplo que viene en el README del repo que te he pasado. En caso de que tengas problemas te recomiendo TuesPechkin(https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin), no es tan bueno como puppeteer pero funciona razonablemente bien.

Comment: Si te decantas por puppeteer simplemente puedes usar bootstrap ya que puppeteer internamente utiliza V8 para hacer un renderizado interno y de ahí generar el PDF. Si utilizas la otra librería tengo una plantilla preparada y una configuración para usar un subconjunto de bootstrap 3. Te lo puedo pasar sin ningún problema.

Comment: @RobertoPintosLópez Tiene buena pinta puppeteer pero hay un ejemplo de como usa el css? ya que con itextsharp es todo inline, con puppeteer debo de trabajar como si fuese un proyecto normal poniendo una sección de css o una clase, otra pregunta voy a injectar el html osea lo tomare como un string me imagino no se renderiza como es el caso de itextsharp?

Comment: @PedroÁvila El css puede ser inline o en una etiqueta style dentro del head.  También puedes usar una url absoluta para acceder al recurso que deseas y si existe Puppeteer lo cargará igual que cargaría un fuera un navegador web. Para generar el pdf tomarás un string, si tiene parámetros realizarás la sustitución antes y puppeteer generará el PDF. Puedes ver un ejemplo en https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp#inject-html